# Error getting file length for [segments_XX] in Solr 6.1

Tags: solr, sitecore8, solr6

We are getting below error when sitecore 8 content management website is using Solr 6.1. Please advice.

> WARN true
>   LukeRequestHandler
>   Error getting file length for [segments_7c]
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: G:\Solr\Solr61\server\solr\itembucket_prod\data\index\segments_7c
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:193)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.size(Files.java:2332)
>       at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:243)
>       at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.fileLength(NRTCachingDirectory.java:128)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler.getFileLength(LukeRequestHandler.java:597)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler.getIndexInfo(LukeRequestHandler.java:585)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.getCoreStatus(CoreAdminOperation.java:968)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation$4.call(CoreAdminOperation.java:170)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler$CallInfo.call(CoreAdminHandler.java:367)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:158)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:156)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:663)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:445)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Sounds like your index has been corrupted, a file has been deleted or is missing. This can happen if the server is restarted / loses power while a commit is happening under fluke situations. You can try the CheckIndex tool for Lucene, or start cleaning up empty files - but take a backup of your index first. If you can reindex I'd just wipe the index clean (stop solr, delete the data directory, start solr and reindex again)

Comment: have the same issue